# 12.10 installing problem on Asus ux32v

Tags: 12.10, asus, ultrabook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I have an Asus UX32VD 6 gb ram hd400 and nvidia 620m graphics. I am starting the installation but after the selection (try or install ubuntu) it's waiting at black screen. So i cant install. Please help i dont like windows.

(i tried all of the options at startup screen. Noacpi, nomodeset etc... did not work)